# getline previous line in c

Tags: c, getline

Is there a way to use getline() to get the previous line from a file? Currently am using fseek to get the offset of a file but when i use getline to get the information at that specific area in the file, getline skips the current line and then gives me the nextline.

For example this is my file that I'm reading:

```
2424,Industrial,$77.38,5443371953372009,mastercard
7890,Home,$76.88,5893085376198065,maestro
1081,Music,$83.63,6397084381203605,instapayment
```

Once I use `fseek(input_file, index[i]->offset, SEEK_SET);` it sets the pointer to the start of `7890,Home,$76.88,5893085376198065,maestro`. Then using getline, it skips that entry and goes to `1081,Music,$83.63,6397084381203605,instapayment`.

Comment: `getline` will get the next line from the current offset.  Most probably the `offset` you're passing to `fseek` is the beginning of the next line, so that is what you're reading.  Probably you're using `ftell` *after* reading the line to get the offset -- which will give you the offset after the line (the start of the next line).

Comment: Please show a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).